# Como jogar um bloco em cima do outro bloco?

Tags: html, css

Eu gostaria de criar uma `div`, contendo um bloco de texto e uma imagem, e a imagem precisa tampar o texto, ao passar o mouse na imagem, imagem tornara semi transparente, mostrando assim o texto que esta embaixo dele

Algo do tipo

```
<div>
    <span>Meu texto de exemplo aqui</span>
    <img src='www.imagem.com.br/imagem123.jpg' alt="" />
</div>
```

Como eu faria isso em `css`?

Comment: Poste um exemplo do que tu fez, e o que está acontecendo para podermos ajudar melhor.

Comment: Alguns exemplos de _hover_ com CSS: **[com animação ou popup](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38497/70)** | **[com sprites](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37676/70)**

Answer (score 1):

É o que o nosso amigo [William Barbosa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15346/william-barbosa) respondeu em  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41337/18328

> Solução simples com `:hover`
>
> Note que eu adicionei classes para não ter que usar o seletor diretamente no nome do elemento, aconselho que faça o mesmo no seu `html`.

Só que para evitar que os elementos após o elemento `div`, que contem a imagem e o texto, é necessário definir as propriedades dele.

Ex.:

```css
.box{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.texto, .imagem {
  position: absolute;
}

.imagem:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <span class="texto"> Lai32290 </span>
    <img class="imagem" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6G8.jpg?s=128&g=1' alt="" />
</div>
<div class="box">
    <span class="texto"> Lai32290 </span>
    <img class="imagem" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6G8.jpg?s=128&g=1' alt="" />
</div>
```

Dê uma olhada neste link http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-image-captions/, têm uns bons exemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Solução simples com `:hover`

Note que eu adicionei classes para não ter que usar o seletor diretamente no nome do elemento, aconselho que faça o mesmo no seu `html`.

```css
.texto, .imagem {
  position: absolute;
}

.imagem:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="texto"> Lai32290 </span>
    <img class="imagem" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS6G8.jpg?s=128&g=1' alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Isso deu certo sim, porem como tenho mais elementos depois da imagem, eles perderam alinhamento

Comment: Eu queria fazer o mesmo efeito desse site http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/50772.html, entre na pagina de Produto desse site